# Hibernate - Get a row with only one value of a composite primary key?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a table (Oracle database) that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
    idEx INTEGER,
    idAdh INTEGER,
    date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (idEx, idAdh)
)
```

I have generated the corresponding classes in Netbeans and I have two classes created for this table: `Example.java` and `ExampleId.java`, this last one containing the two values of my primary key.

Now let's say I have some records here and I would like to delete one using only one value of the primary key (`idEx` for example, which is unique too). So first I need to `get` that row, but I can't find a way to do this. Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
Example ex = (Example) session.get(Example.class, new ExampleId(?, idEx));
```

I'd need something to replace that `?` that would act as a wildcard.

Or maybe this is absolutely not the way to go and in this case I'd really appreciate some advices.

Comment: wait are you saying that `idEx` by itself is unique?  In that case, why is the key a compound key?

Comment: it's an associative class, `idEx` and `idAdh` are PKs of two other tables.

Comment: Just use surrogate keys, always, forever, in new code.  It's worth it.

Comment: If this is an association table on a many-to-many relationship, then wouldn't you get back more than one row when querying on only one side of the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the `ex` with a HQL query.

Comment: It works with the HQL query. But is there no way to achieve this without a query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get this without an HQL/JPQL/Criteria query, for good reason.

The `get` method returns a single object and automatically generates a query like `select * from table where key = :key`.

The only way you can guarantee that this query returns exactly one row is when you specify the entire key.   If you don't have the full PK object available, the query will return a *list* of objects, at which point `get` is not appropriate anymore.